# remove above/below line and append to a file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file with the following lines. I can filter a specific word and display the lines below/above it. However, i also wanted to remove it on the original file and append it to a new file.

```
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>green</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
</tr>
```

i can do it this by: `grep -i green origfile -A1 -B1 >> newfile` but how can remove it from the orig file.

**origfile:**

```
    <tr>
    <td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
    </tr>
```

**newfile:**

```
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>green</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a cleaner/quickest way to do it?

Comment: unrelated to your question, but you can use `-C2` instead of `-A1 -B1`. just thought i'd share

Comment: @kevinnls `-C1`, no?

Comment: oops. yes `-C1`. thank you @BenjaminW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it within a single `awk`, segregating records into different files. This will look for word `green` and will place one line before and after it and output it into new file along with removing it from original file.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/green/){
    words[FNR]
  }
  next
}
((FNR+1) in words) || (FNR in words) || ((FNR-1) in words){
  print > "newfile"
  next
}
1
' Input_file Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                    ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first time Input_file is being read.
  if($0~/green/){           ##Checking condition if line contains green string then do following.
    words[FNR]              ##Creating array of words with index of current line number.
  }
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
((FNR+1) in words) || (FNR in words) || ((FNR-1) in words){
##Checking condition if current line+1 OR current line OR current line-1 numbers are in words array then do following.
  print > "newfile"         ##Printing current line into newfile output file.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                           ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file 
                            ##Mentioning Input_file(s) and doing inplace save into it.
```

Comment: [not OP]: could you please elaborate on how this works? (just want to learn)

Comment: @kevinnls, yeah I am in process of writing detailed explanation, please do give me few mins :)

Comment: @kevinnls, a detailed explanation is added in my answer now, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, i did try it but it's still (green) on the origfile.

Comment: @gafm, sorry there was a typo, please try my edited code once, it should fly, let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: works like a charm. thank you @RavinderSingh13 :)

Comment: @gafm, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `ed` solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s origfile.txt <<-EOF
  /<td>green<\/td>/;?^<tr>?;/^<\/tr>/w newfile.txt
  .;/^<\/tr>/d
  w
  q
EOF
```

Or a separate `ed` script, just name to `script.ed`

```
/<td>green<\/td>/;?^<tr>?;/^<\/tr>/w newfile.txt
.;/^<\/tr>/d
w
q
```

Then

```
ed -s origfile.txt < script.ed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$0 == "<tr>" { inRow=1; row=$0; next }
inRow {
    row = row ORS $0
    if ( $0 == "</tr>" ) {
        inRow = 0
        if ( index(row,"<td>green</td>") ) {
            print row | "cat>&2"
            next
        }
        else {
            $0 = row
        }
    }
}
!inRow
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file >o1 2>o2
```

```
$ head o?
==> o1 <==
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
</tr>

==> o2 <==
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>green</td>
</tr>
```

To modify the original file:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file >o1 2>o2 && mv o1 file
```

```
$ cat file
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>tree</td><td>apple</td><td>red</td>
</tr>
```